# How to specify a storage class to user pvc in kubeflow

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, persistent-storage, storage-class-specifier, kubeflow

I am trying to attach a storage class to all the PVC request created by individual user pods for jupyter notebooks in kubeflow.

I tried editing some values and specify storage_class. but none of it is working, whenever a new pvc comes up it doesnot come with a storage class name.

The desired result is whenever a pvc of user pods comes, it should have the name of storage class attached with it. Kindly help with this. I am stuck from last day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to have a default storage class in your cluster, so if a pvc does not specify any storage class then default one would be selected.

List the StorageClasses in your cluster:

`kubectl get storageclass`

Mark a StorageClass as default:
 set the annotation storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class=true.

`kubectl patch storageclass <your-class-name> -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"}}}'`

Here are the detail steps [change-default-storage-class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-default-storage-class/)

Comment: I do know how to implement using yaml. I am installing kubeflow using ksonnet. I need to know how to add it on that setup

Comment: this change need to be done on k8s side, it will work for all of the applications

Comment: thank you, i figured out the solution, i wanted to assign from pvc side using kf deployment for kubeflow.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)

> While **PersistentVolumeClaims** allow a user to consume abstract storage resources, it is common that users need **PersistentVolumes** with varying properties, such as performance, for different problems.
>   Cluster administrators need to be able to offer a variety of **PersistentVolumes** that differ in more ways than just size and access modes, without exposing users to the details of how those volumes are implemented. For these needs there is the **StorageClass** resource.
>
> A **PersistentVolume** (PV) is a piece of storage in the cluster that has been provisioned by an administrator or dynamically provisioned using Storage Classes.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
name: task-pv-volume
labels:
type: local
spec:
storageClassName: <name_of_your_StorageClass>
capacity:
storage: 10Gi
accessModes:
- ReadWriteOnce
hostPath:
path: "/mnt/data"
```

> A **PersistentVolumeClaim** (PVC) is a request for storage by a user.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
name: task-pv-claim
spec:
storageClassName: <name_of_your_StorageClass>
accessModes:
- ReadWriteOnce
resources:
requests:
storage: 3Gi
```

> Then you can create a Pod that uses your PVC as a volume(which uses PV with storageClass)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: task-pv-pod
spec:
volumes:
- name: task-pv-storage
persistentVolumeClaim:
claimName: task-pv-claim
containers:
- name: task-pv-container
image: nginx
ports:
- containerPort: 80
name: "http-server"
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
name: task-pv-storage
```

> Before you are going to create a PV and PVC [**StorageClass**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) must already exist, if it's not a default one will be used instead.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: <name_of_your_StorageClass>
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - debug
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

You can check your StorageClasses with this command:

```
kubectl get sc
```

Comment: I do know how to implement using yaml. I am installing kubeflow using ksonnet. I need to know how to add it on that setup

Comment: The team behind ksonnet is stepping back from the project. As a result, work on ksonnet will end `https://github.com/ksonnet/ksonnet/tree/04138b998cb26049626280a0c32be21bdd902d3b`

As i could read there `https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/aws/deploy/install-kubeflow/` to install kubeflow you need kubectl,so you can use it to deploy StorageClass on your cluster as @Suresh Vishnoi mentioned.